# In Pylint, how do I disable "Exactly one space after comma" for multidimensional array indices?

Tags: pylint

I like having PyLint check that commas are generally followed by spaces, except in one case: multidimensional indices.  For example, I get the following warning from Pylint:

```
C: 31, 0: Exactly one space required after comma
  num_features = len(X_train[0,:])
                              ^ (bad-whitespace)
```

Is there a way to get rid of the warnings requiring spaces after commas for the case multidimensional arrays, but keep the space-checking logic the same for all other comma uses?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you figured this out by now but for anyone, like me, who happened upon this looking for an answer...

use  # pylint: disable=C0326 on the line that is guilty of this. for instance:
     `num_features = len(X_train[0,:]) #pylint: disable=C0326`

This applies to multiple kinds of space errors. See [pylint wiki](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/messages:c0326)

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Do you know if there is a more succinct way to do this?  It is kind of a pain when I have many multidimensional indices throughout my code.

Answer (score 0):

You'll almost certainly want to disable this via the .pylintrc file for larger situations.

Example, say I have:

```
  x111 = thing.abc(asdf)
  x112_b = thing1.abc(asdf)
  x112_b224 = thing.abc(asdf)
  x112_f = thing1.abc(asdf)
  ... lots more
```

Now, presume I want to visually see the situation:

```
  x111     = thing.abc(asdf)
  x112_b   = thing1.abc(asdf)
  ... lots more
```

so I add the following line to .pylintrc

disable=C0326,C0115,C0116

(note only the first one, c0326, counts, but I'm leaving two other docstring ones there so you can see you just add err messages you want to ignore.)